# Why is Tensorflow web site flower image classification takes about 6 seconds to classify?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I followed the example on [Tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retraining) for image classification.
It worked as expected on my laptop HP with Intel 6th Gen i7 processor (12 GB onboard RAM with shared memory VGA). However, I am surprised to see that the single image classification takes about 6 seconds. Is that typical on a CPU? Also, I get a message that the current Tensorflow binary I am using does not support AVX which my processor supports. So I should get some speed bump with the right binary but is it possible to takes 6 seconds to a single image?
I will use a GPU card in my final install, but is there anything else I should work on to improve the speed? I need several images to be classified in one second.

Classification command :

```
python label_image.py \
--graph=/tmp/output_graph.pb --labels=/tmp/output_labels.txt \
--input_layer=Placeholder \
--output_layer=final_result \
--image=$HOME/flower_photos/daisy/21652746_cc379e0eea_m.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Running time of `label_image.py` will also include loading of the classification model, deserialization of it and loading your image. In a production environment, you need to have a message queueing system which your classification  script will read from and write to. You can build one with Redis, This pipeline will reduce I/O overhead and you will end up with a reasonable classification time. You can see an example [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/02/05/deep-learning-production-keras-redis-flask-apache/)